# Convertir una cadena de caracteres tipo string a numero entero en javascript dentro de un array

Tags: javascript

```
function igualCantidadCaracteres(strings, caracteres) {
  // La función llamada 'igualCantidadCaracteres', recibe como argumento un arreglo de strings llamado 'strings'
  // y un numero entero llamado 'caracteres'
  // Debe devolver en un array los strings que tengan el numero de caracteres coincidentes con 'caracteres'
  // Ej:
  // mismaCantidadCaracteres(['ah', 'hola', 'que pasa', 'yo'], 2) debe retornar ['yo'] ya que 'yo' tiene 2 caracteres
  // mismaCantidadCaracteres(['javascript', 'jorge', 'amiga', 'puerta']
```

> necesito devolver el valor de una cadena de caracteres dentro de un array y despues comparar entre elementos los que son iguales en javascript

Mis dudas:

- ¿tengo que ocupar dos variables i y j?
- ¿Tengo que usar algun if o un for?
- ¿como puedo retornar este valor?.

Comment: Para poderte ayudar de manera mas efectiva por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega que has intentado

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar la programación funcional, existen varios tipos de metodos que se aplican a un array, reduces código ya no ocupas un for o dos.

- **Filter** es un método que hace un 'filtrado' en base a una condición verdadera.
- El método igualCantidadCaracteres retorna un arreglo 'filtrado' con la condición  **string.length === caracteres** donde la condición verdadera es la palabra que tenga como length la cantidad de caracteres que solicitas.

Te dejo un ejemplo espero te sirva. :D

```js
function igualCantidadCaracteres(strings, caracteres) {
  return strings.filter(string => string.length === caracteres);
}
const result1 = igualCantidadCaracteres(['ah', 'hola', 'que pasa', 'yo'], 2)
const result2 = igualCantidadCaracteres(['javascript', 'jorge', 'amiga', 'puerta'], 5)

console.log("Palabras con length == 2",result1);
console.log("Palabras con length == 5",result2);
```

Comment: En estos casos compañero, lo que se recomienda es esperar a que el OP (quien hizo la pregunta) muestre lo que ha intentado ya que de otro modo su pregunta puede terminar cerrada

Answer (score 0):

```
function igualCantidadCaracteres(strings, caracteres) {
  var tmp = []; /* Crea un array */
  for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) /* Recorre los strings */ {                               
    if(strings[i].length == caracteres) /* Si el tamaño del string actual es igual a caracteres */ {                 
      tmp.push(strings[i].toString()); /* Entonces añádelo a mi array. */
    }
  }
  /* Cuando se acabe de recorrer todo. */
  return tmp; /* retorna el array al que le fuí guardando los strings que tenían el tamaño indicado */
}
```

Recuerda que no hay una fórmula exacta para resolver un problema. Podrías resolverlo de un montón de formas válidas. Algunos prefieren eficiencia, otros códigos cortos, otros algoritmos sencillos, otros código muy fácil de leer... Depende del programa y las preferencias de cada uno.

Te recomiendo buscar libros de javascript en pdfdrive.com y seguir los cursos / usar de referencia rápida w3schools y mozilla.